# xcodeでアップロードファイルの検証の際、エラーが表示される

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode6, xcode7

プログラミング初心者です。
作成したアプリを初めてappleに申請したいと思っています。
Xcodeからアプリをアップロードする際、調べてはみたものの解決できない問題に直面してしまいました。

Productメニューから「Archive」を選んだ後、アプリのデータをアップロードしても問題ないか検証のために「Validation」をクリックした後にエラーとなりました。
以下、エラー内容及びキャプチャー画像です。

Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets:
Xcode attempted to locate or generate matching signing assets and failed to do so because of the following issues.
Missing iOS Distribution signing identity for 私の名前
Xcode can request one for you

Visit Member Center or Import Developer Profile

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
エラーメッセージを読むと、「Xcodeはその問題を解決できます。」といった内容を
述べていると思うのですが、どこをどう治すべきなのか分からなくなってきました。

iOS Developer Programの登録、AppIDの作成、プロビジョニングプロファイルは
作成しています。
また、iTunes Connectでは必要な情報(スクリーンショットなど)は登録してますので、
残りはビルドだけの状況です。
お手数をおかけいたしますが、ご教示頂けますでしょうか。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 英語で書かれた手順ですが、[この回答](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35406327/1167750)はお役に立てばよいのですが。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちらが参考になるかと。
http://egg-is-world.com/2016/02/17/missing-ios-distribution-signing/

古いWWDR Certificateを削除して作り直せばよさそうです。

Comment: URLの手順に沿いWWDR削除とインストールで作成したアプリを申請できました。とても参考になりました。